# Tensorflow tf.divide how to use

Tags: tensorflow

I am very very new to tensorflow. I am trying to understand its basics. Based on some examples I created simple script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

test_data_size = 2000
iterations = 50000
learn_rate = 0.005


def generate_test_values():
    train_x = []
    train_y = []

    for _ in xrange(test_data_size):
        x = np.random.rand()
        y_f = 8 / x
        train_y.append(y_f)
        train_x.append(x)

    return np.transpose([train_x]), np.transpose([train_y])


train_dataset,train_values = generate_test_values()

a = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name="a")
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="idf")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
model = tf.divide(a, x)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - model))
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)

    for _ in xrange(iterations):
        session.run(train, feed_dict={
            x: train_dataset,
            y: train_values
        })

    print "cost = {}".format(session.run(cost, feed_dict={
        x: train_dataset,
        y: train_values
    }))

    print "a = {}".format(session.run(a))
```

it delivers simple data to predict y=1/x function. Unfortunately it does not work all a get is:

cost = nan a = [nan]

Though it is working with linear model y=ax.

Can anyone explain me why it is not working.

Comment: It seems that when you use a non-linear model, you make a division by zero, which will obviously give [nan]. I think that you should double-check what values are passed through the Tensor Graph that you build. You can debug by enabling EagerExecution of TensorFlow which will allow you to implement calculations directly, being able to implement your calculations before on-flight. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager

Comment: You can evaluate the value of _cost_ in the trainig  _sess.run()_  and append the values in each iteration. In that way you can evaluate the cost in every training step